# How to find elements in a list of custom objects that have specific value of [Flags] enum

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

Given this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Result
{
    None = 0,
    Draw = 1 << 0,
    Win = 1 << 1,
    Loss = 1 << 2,
    NotLost = Draw | Win,
    NotWon = Draw | Loss,
    Any = Draw | Win | Loss
}
```

and this class:

```
public class Match
{
    public Result Result { get; }

    ...
}
```

How can I get a list of object `Match` where property `Result` has the flag `NotWon` out of a `List<Match> matches`?

I've tried `matches.FindAll(m => m.Result.HasFlag(Result.NotWon));` but it's always empty, while `matches.FindAll(m => m.Result.HasFlag(Result.Loss));` works as intended.

Comment: Seems to work [just fine](https://rextester.com/POKG94747). I suspect that your logic is incorrect though. Note that `Result.NotWon.HasFlag(Result.Loss)` would return true, not the other way around (i.e., `Result.Loss.HasFlag(Result.NotWon)` returns false). Are you sure there's no confusion about this?

Comment: I'm new to using ```[Flags] enum```, so my thought process was to use NotLost, NotWon and Any as some kind of helper when looking for results. The code itself will only create matches using Draw, Loss or Win. Changed your code example to represent what I was thinking: https://rextester.com/UUHN12601

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. No, that's not how flags work. Check Joe's answer below; he explains it in more detail.

Comment: A side note: while HasFlag works fine, it is better to user `(value & Result.NotWon) == Result.NotWon` as this avoid [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` operator is a *bitwise* OR, not a logical OR. Thus `NotWon` means "the value where **both** Draw and Loss bits are set".

`NotWon` = `Draw | Loss` = `(1 << 0) | (1 << 2)` = `1 | 4` = `0b0001 | 0b0100` = `0b0101` = `5`.

Since `Enum.HasFlag` [is a shorthand for `this & flag == flag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), it will only evaluate to `true` if `m.Result` has both bits set. It will evaluate to false if only one of the bits are set.

There are two ways to get what you want that I can think of:

1. Remove the `Not...` cases from your enum. Just check if the flag you don't want is set, and then invert the result, i.e. `matches.FindAll(m => !m.Result.HasFlag(Result.Win))`.
2. Use the `Not...` cases as *masks* and check for non-zero, e.g. `matches.FindAll(m => (m.Result & Result.NotWon) != 0)`.

Comment: Ah, got it now, thanks! Solution works well, just a little sidequestion whiche doesn't need it's own thread I think:

I've removed all the ```Not...``` and ```Any``` cases and everything works as expected, but when I try to get any results not being ```None``` like ```matches.FindAll(m => !m.Result.HasFlag(Result.None));``` it's still returning an empty list. Vice versa it's giving me all results when looking for the ones being ```None```. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just check for equality with None, `m => m.Result != Result.None`. Because `anything & 0` is 0, so the `HasFlag` method can't really handle enums with value `0` correctly. This is the unfortunate thing about C#'s flag-style enums, is that you have to be a bit more aware of the way the binary math works.